# how do i control the order of execution of cucumber tests

Tags: android, testing, cucumber, acceptance-testing

I want to split my tests in different files

- login.feature
- student.feature
- item.feature
- logout.feature

Login.feature need to be my first script to run  because for other tests I need to be logged in (I will disable the reinstall app between feature).

So I need to make sure that my first test is the login and my last test is logout, I don't care is run first student or item.

Comment: The argument will be that your tests shouldn't be order-dependent.

Comment: You could use @tags or use background to login before each feature.